# new to android - only able to login to facebook when hash key is in the person's developer's account

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook SDK comes with a login and post app called: HelloFacebookSample. When I login it works fine, but if anyone else logs in there, it wont work. The reason is because it only accepts those facebook accounts who are developers and have the applications key hash assigned in their facebook developer's dashboard.

Example, if I make my john doe facebook uers a facebook developer and assign the key hash in his dashboard, go back to my phone and launch my app and try to login as John doe.. it works fine. But i should have to ask my users to have to do that... is there any way around this? I tried to look through the documentation but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook uses this as a method of protection. As long as your app is in Sandbox mode on the Facebook Developer page, only accounts who have added their hash key to the app page have access to it. When releasing the app, change the app out of Sandbox mode and this safety feature will no longer be required

Comment: logged into the dashboard, and changed the setting: Sandbox Mode: disabled.   still not able to log in, but it states i needs several minutes to propagate the changes... so i will wait.

Comment: it's Alive ... u created a monster! thanks for the solution - it worked.